# Magento 2.0.7 to 2.1 - Error in Review Order Page - "We cant place the order"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout

Steps to reproduce

Install Magento 2.1
Add any product to cart
Hit Go TO Checkout Select Checkout with Paypal Option Login and Hit PayNow
Expected result

After Hitting PayPal Pay Now button - success page should display (Skip Review Page is Enabled in PayPal Website Payment Method")
There should be option to CREATE an account on success page

Actual result

Takes to Review Page - with "We can't place the order." in RED
Surprisingly - The Order will already been placed by now "Before you hit - Place Order at bottom of Rewiew Page. You can basically do nothing on this page as the order is already placed, and "we cant place the order continues"
With Magento 2.1, the PayPal checkout does not provide option to create account - unsure if it would have provided this option if I could go beyond the Review Page -----to success page

Answer (score 0):

There is ticket for this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4785.

It's really annoying/pity such thing happens.